# If a cell change call a macro

Tags: vba, excel

The following code not working - please guide me

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    Set target = Range("D11")
    If target.value = "Yes" Then
        Call main
    End If
    If target.value = "No" Then
        Call Main2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `please guide me` - [please see the guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For starters, we have no idea what "not working" means.

Comment: `Target` is passed to the code - it references the cell you just changed so there's no need to try and set a value to it.  All you need to do is read the value of `Target` that is passed when you change the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you’re after this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    If Target.Address <> "$D$11" Then Exit Sub ‘ if the changed cell is not $D$11 then do nothing

    If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        Main
    ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
        Main2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to add a last `Else` in the `If` block:  `Else: MsgBox "What am I meant to do with '" & Target.Value & "'?", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion`